# React Native Create View Under Battery / Clock Bar

Tags: react-native

I learn React Native 2 days ago and start creating a header or menu bar, which is placed under `View` tag . But, I notice that the `View` tag start from top-left of the entire screen.

I believe that battery / clock bar in iOS and Android has different height. so, how to place a `View` component under battery / clock bar?

like this :

[image]

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can import statusBar [FOR MORE](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/status-bar/)

```
<StatusBar backgroundColor = "#00BCD4" translucent = {true}/>
```